# Import images with Create-React-App dynamically

Tags: reactjs, image, object, webpack, components

I hope that somebody can help me with my problem.

I started learning React and I want to display images dynamically from an object named "project".

I am looping inside "projects" and pass each item as props of a component "Project".

It displays the other items (name, description, alt) but I can't get the images.
I tried this method : `` <img src={require(`./img/${project.image}`)} `` but it doesn't work. 
There is no error message, but it shows nothing.

I saw a lot of people have the same problem, but I tried everything...I don't know what to do.

This is my object:

[image: projects list]

The organization of my folder:

[image: folder]

My component Project:

[image: component Project]

And the website:

[image: what I have on the screen]

Comment: Is `<img src={/img/${project.image}}>` working?

Comment: I believe you have to import the pictures individually before you can use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys ! I found a way to do it. 
I first imported the images to my object file "projects". 
Then I imported my object and I made a loop

[import images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j3Gt.png)

[loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siYMM.png)

Finally, my component Project
[component Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtpRR.png)

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use require. It will work if you use it that way.

```
<img src={`./img/${project.image}`} alt={project.alt} />
```

I hope that will be useful.